# Shopping cart to send out email to me when "purchase button" is clicked. PLS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

That is all I have, I managed to create the cart (with online training and help), but it feels impossible to me to be able to send out the list of items in the cart (and price) to my email when clients click on the ORDINA button. Any help?

I've tried mailto but it won't work, I have 0 idea on how to do this, please I would love to understand

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Grazie per il tuo ordine')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('Già inserito, modifica la quantità nella sezione ordine')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">RIMUOVI</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('€', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100 + 1.5
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '€' + total 
}
```

```html
<body>
  
            <h2 class="band-name band-name-large">ORDER</h2>
       </header>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">Pizze</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Margherita</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="5.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">€3.50</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ORDINA</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Viennese</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="5.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">€4.50</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button"type="button">ORDINA</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Contadina</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="5.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">€4.50</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ORDINA</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Norcia e Funghi</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="5.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">€5.00</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ORDINA</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">ORDINE</h2>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">PIZZA</span>
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PREZZO</span>
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITA'</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-items">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-total">
                <strong class="cart-total-title">Totale</strong>
                <span class="cart-total-price">€0</span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">ORDINA</button>
        </section>
    

        <footer class="main-footer">
            <div class="container main-footer-container">
                <h3 class="band-name">Pizza</h3>
                <ul class="nav footer-nav">
                
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Client-side JS cannot send emails by itself. You need access to a mail server. You can either send an AJAX request to your local server (and write PHP/ASP/Python etc code to send the emails yourself), or you can pay for a third party service to do it for you (eg SendGrid)

Answer (score 0):

javascipt from the browser cannot send email it self:

they can have 2 scenario for this:

- is to call an web-api on a server who can send smtp email
- can invoke a link via email-to which needs client-user himself send email with his/her email-client-software

like this:

```
<a href="mailto:email@example.com?cc=secondemail@example.com, anotheremail@example.com, &bcc=lastemail@example.com&subject=Mail from our Website&body=Some body text here">Send Email</a>
```

in this scenario you can make the purcache link to have this cart content in its href-body attribute.

because you call The updateTotalFunction each time your cart content has get changed. you need to place these code at the end of the function declaration :

Code Snipped:

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

//    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Grazie per il tuo ordine')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('Già inserito, modifica la quantità nella sezione ordine')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">RIMUOVI</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('€', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100 + 1.5
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '€' + total;
    
    let cartContentElements =document.getElementsByClassName('cart-column');
    let cartContent = "";
    for(let i=0;i< cartContentElements.length; i++){
        cartContent += cartContentElements[i].innerHTML;
    }
    cartContent = cartContent.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'').replace(/ /g,'');
    cartContent = encodeURI(cartContent);
    //console.log(cartContent);
    
    document.getElementById("purcache-link").href = "mailto:shopmanager@shop.com?&subject=Cart Items for Purcache&body=" + cartContent ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
            <h2 class="band-name band-name-large">ORDER</h2>
       </header>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">Pizze</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Margherita</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="5.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">€3.50</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ORDINA</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Viennese</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="5.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">€4.50</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button"type="button">ORDINA</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Contadina</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="5.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">€4.50</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ORDINA</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Norcia e Funghi</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="5.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">€5.00</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ORDINA</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">ORDINE</h2>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">PIZZA</span>
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PREZZO</span>
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITA'</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-items cart-content">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-total cart-content">
                <strong class="cart-total-title">Totale</strong>
                <span class="cart-total-price">€0</span>
            </div>
            <!--<button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">ORDINA</button>-->
            <a  id='purcache-link'>ORDINA</a>
        </section>
    

        <footer class="main-footer">
            <div class="container main-footer-container">
                <h3 class="band-name">Pizza</h3>
                <ul class="nav footer-nav">
                
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
```

your receiving email contained URIEncoded Cart which you have to decode it by yourself.

good luck.

Comment: let's say I want to add the href mailto link, how do I make it already filled with the information inserted in the cart? that is my major issue

Comment: i bring example in the answer.

Comment: can you provide the code snippet? this is not working for me but I like the idea ://

Comment: i am working on it it has a flaw i will correct it in minutes

Comment: just run it, it does work indeed, it just doesn't add the quantity on it :// omg I'm going crazy ahah

Comment: because the cart data in html is not well formed and it was very hard to get it. and when i want to send it to email-client application because its get more than 255 chars in uri. it wasnt work. so i had to eliminate the html tags and the quantity of the cart items was on input tag value. if you put the quantity in an span or div tag after the price and add class name card-column which can be retrieve further. it will be added on email too.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I am trying to comprehend but I don't understand what you mean exactly? would you be able to help me a little bit more?

Comment: you get data from user with input tag. your input tag has the data (cart item quantity) in its value attribute ( <input value='2'  /> )

Comment: but for sending data to email-client-application like (thunderbird google-email ...) i have to put data in this ( <a href="mailto: body=.... " /> . The href value should be an url. and url has a limit of 256 character.

Comment: so i couldnt to put the whole  ( let cartContentElements =document.getElementsByClassName('cart-column'); ) with all children in the href, because with these tags it gets more than 256 chars

Comment: and i have to eliminate the additives like tags and their attributes and just preserve the plain texts. with this code :  ( cartContent = cartContent.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'').replace(/ /g,''); )

Comment: honestly the html structure wasnt very good to keep track all of cart data together and with this quantity which has been capped in the <input value , i couldnt done anymore.

Comment: i have suggested that you grap the <input value and put it in a tag which can be getElement

Comment: Thank you, I have tried but not succeeded, I am sure I am missing out on something. Being a noob doesn't help unfortunately