# Contact form sending message to specified address

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering how would I be able to send the message entered from the form box above, to a specific email address, while using the users entered email as the sending address? Is this possible to accomplish through html or would I have to use some sort of JavaScript to accomplish this? Anything helps and thanks in advance!

```js
<script>
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input");

function focusFunc() {
  let parent = this.parentNode;
  parent.classList.add("focus");
}

function blurFunc() {
  let parent = this.parentNode;
  if (this.value == "") {
    parent.classList.remove("focus");
  }
}

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("focus", focusFunc);
  input.addEventListener("blur", blurFunc);
});
</script>
```

```css
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
@font-face { font-family: Raleway; src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');}


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
input,
textarea {
  font-family: Raleway;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 820px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.contact-form {
  background-color: #3A81B4;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 20%, #2d6a96);
  position: absolute;
}

.circle.one {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  top: 130px;
  right: -40px;
}

.circle.two {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 30px;
}

.contact-form:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #3A81B4;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 50px;
  left: -13px;
}

form {
  padding: 2.3rem 2.2rem;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #fafafa;
  background: none;
  padding: 0.6rem 1.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

textarea.input {
  padding: 0.8rem 1.2rem;
  min-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.input-container label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 0 0.4rem;
  color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.input-container.textarea label {
  top: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.6rem 1.3rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fafafa;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  color: #1880c9;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

.input-container span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 0 0.4rem;
  color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 500;
}

.input-container span:before,
.input-container span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #3A81B4;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.input-container span:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.input-container span:after {
  right: 50%;
}

.input-container.focus label {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.input-container.focus span:before,
.input-container.focus span:after {
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.contact-info {
  padding: 2.3rem 2.2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.contact-info .title {
  color: #1880c9;
}

.text {
  color: #333;
  margin: 1.5rem 0 2rem 0;
}

.information {
  display: flex;
  color: #555;
  margin: 0.7rem 0;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
}

.icon {
  width: 28px;
  margin-right: 0.7rem;
}

.social-media {
  padding: 2rem 0 0 0;
}

.social-media p {
  color: #333;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.social-icons a {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #3A81B4, #2d6a96);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.social-icons a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(181%, 11%);
  opacity: 0.2;
}

@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .form {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }

  .contact-info:before {
    bottom: initial;
    top: -75px;
    right: 65px;
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }

  .contact-form:before {
    top: -13px;
    left: initial;
    right: 70px;
  }

  .square {
    transform: translate(140%, 43%);
    height: 350px;
  }

  .big-circle {
    bottom: 75%;
    transform: scale(0.9) translate(-40%, 30%);
    right: 50%;
  }

  .text {
    margin: 1rem 0 1.5rem 0;
  }

  .social-media {
    padding: 1.5rem 0 0 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    padding: 1.5rem;
  }

  .contact-info:before {
    display: none;
  }

  .square,
  .big-circle {
    display: none;
  }

  form,
  .contact-info {
    padding: 1.7rem 1.6rem;
  }

  .text,
  .information,
  .social-media p {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .title {
    font-size: 1.15rem;
  }

  .social-icons a {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }

  .icon {
    width: 23px;
  }

  .input {
    padding: 0.45rem 1.2rem;
  }

  .btn {
    padding: 0.45rem 1.2rem;
  }
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <span class="big-circle"></span>
      <img class="square" alt="" />
      <div class="form">
        <div class="contact-info">
          <h3 class="title">Let's get <b>in touch</b></h3>
          <p class="text">
            Feel free to send us an email with any inquiries; one of our receptionists will reach out to you as sson as possible.
          </p>

          <div class="info">
            <div class="information">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sefyudem/Contact-Form-HTML-CSS/master/img/location.png  " class="icon" alt="" />
              <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="information">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sefyudem/Contact-Form-HTML-CSS/master/img/email.png" class="icon" alt="" />
              <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="information">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sefyudem/Contact-Form-HTML-CSS/master/img/phone.png" class="icon" alt="" />
              <p></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="social-media">
            <p>Connect with us :</p>
            <div class="social-icons">
              <a href="#">
               
      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contact-form">
          <span class="circle one"></span>
          <span class="circle two"></span>

          <form action="index.html" autocomplete="off">
            <h3 class="title">Contact us</h3>
            <div class="input-container">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="input" />
              <label for="">Username</label>
              <span>Username</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="input" />
              <label for="">Email</label>
              <span>Email</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
              <input type="tel" name="phone" class="input" />
              <label for="">Phone</label>
              <span>Phone</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container textarea">
              <textarea name="message" class="input"></textarea>
              <label for="">Message</label>
              <span>Message</span>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes just use some link like this for in html to send an email:

```
<a id="email-link" href="mailto:email@example.com?cc=secondemail@example.com, anotheremail@example.com, &bcc=lastemail@example.com&subject=Mail from our Website&body=Some body text here">Send Email</a>
```

and you can make it change when user change the box message:

```
function changeLinkHref(){
    let message_content = document.getElementById("message-text-area").value;
    let name = document.getElementById("name-input").value;
    document.getElementById("email-link").href = "mailto:yourmail@yourdomain.zone?&subject=subject&body=" + name + "%0A" + message_content ;
}
```

and call the function when text-area and text input get changed.

in a tag href attribute body section you can append your email text with htmlEncodedNewLine (%0A)

Comment: Right, but that wouldn't pull the users message from the contact form or have the users sending address pulled as well?

Comment: i didnt understood, you want that a user to change the email repentance address or want user to spoof their email address?

Comment: The user will fill out their name, email address, phone number and message. Once they hit send, it needs to send the message to a specific email address. When the receiver gets the email, it should pull the senders name, phone and message and show which email address it came from (when the user entered into the form)

Comment: so it can be done via html a tag. user will send email using this trick with his/her own email address and his/her own email-client application.

Comment: Right, I tried something like this before, but nothing actually happens. When the submit button is clicked, nothing changes.

Comment: it should be a tag (not button) because i have tried and it has been worked.

Comment: for example : this question has something related with emailto stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65036771/shopping-cart-to-send-out-email-to-me-when-purchase-button-is-clicked-pls/65036883?noredirect=1#comment114983298_65036883

Comment: Yeah, used a tag, could be a browser issue maybe? Are you running google chrome?